# NameError: name 'self' is not defined in <script> at line number 6

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am new to python and am trying to write code that connects to a irc server. I am inputing the code into a NiFi ExecuteScript processor and trying to execute. I get the error below, when running it. I am not sure if it's NiFi causing the issue or just the code it's self.

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined in  at line number 6

```
import socket
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  self.ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  self.server = "irc.freenode.net"
  self.channel = ""
  self.botnick = ""
  self.ircsock.connect((server, 6667))
  self.ircsock.send(bytes("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick + " " + botnick + "\n"))
  self.ircsock.send(bytes("NICK "+ botnick +"\n"))

  def joinchan(self, chan):
    self.ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN "+ chan +"\n"))
    ircmsg = ""
    while ircmsg.find("End of /NAMES list.") == -1:
      self.ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048)
      self.ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r')
      print(ircmsg)

  def ping(self):
    self.ircsock.send(bytes("PONG :pingis\n"))

  def sendmsg(self, msg, target=channel):
    self.ircsock.send(bytes("PRIVMSG "+ target +" :"+ msg +"\n"))



flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
  flowFile = session.write(flowFile,PyStreamCallback())
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

Comment: You have wrong indentation. Looks like the line starting with `self.ircsock = ` and the following lines should be part of the `__init__` method.

Comment: @azro that isn't how pass works. The problem here is the rest of it is intended outside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init function is not properly indented

```py
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback): 
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        self.ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "irc.freenode.net" 
        self.channel = "" self.botnick = ""
        self.ircsock.connect((server, 6667))
        self.ircsock.send(bytes("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick + " " + botnick + "\n")) 
        self.ircsock.send(bytes("NICK "+ botnick +"\n"))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my initial issue. I think my indentation is all over the place. It's now complaining about, name channel is not defined.